# Matching left alignment of custom section header view with other standard headers and cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

In a UITableView (plain style) with dynamic prototype cells and mostly standard headers and footers, I had to replace one header with a custom view.

This was easily done by creating a UIView in the storyboard inside the affected table view (next to, but outside of the cell prototypes), connecting it to an outlet and returning that outlet in the `viewForHeaderInSection` method.

This view has some content, of course, and I want to left-align it with all the rest. The standard margin however is different for iPhone/iPad and it also changes with orientation.

From which property can I retrieve the currently needed left margin?

Setting it programmatically via an outlet to a suitable auto-layout constraint is easy again, but where do I get the value to use from?

(This question is similar to [Matching left alignment of custom & standard UITableViewCell types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349917/matching-left-alignment-of-custom-standard-uitableviewcell-types), but for headers, not cells)

Answer (score 0):

The value obtained from

```
self.tableView.separatorInset.left
```

seems to do the trick. The auto-layout constraint for the margin should be set in the `viewForHeaderInSection` method. Call `self.tableView.reloadData()` when you detect device rotation to keep it up to date.